# Word VBA Font.Hidden property becomes unreadable if selection is in table and selection is big

Tags: vba, fonts, properties, ms-word, hidden

This is very easy to replicate....Please follow my steps with MS Word.

In a Word file, create a fairly large table (of about five columns and twenty rows). Populate all cells with some junk text.
Or, pick a "good sized" table in a file that you already have.

1. Select (or "Highlight") a few rows of the table, such as three rows.
2. Go to the Font section of the Word Ribbon. Notice that the Hidden
   property of the selection is showing as "not checked" which means
   visible. This is what you expect to see (for now).
3. Optionally, also go to the Immediate Window of the VB Editor and
   type "? Selection.Range.Font.Hidden". Word will respond "0", meaning
   the .Hidden property is false. This is another way of verifying what
   you saw in Step 2.
4. Now select an *additional* few rows of the table. Go to Step 2 and repeat.

By the time your Selection gets up to about 12 rows (your results may vary somewhat), the Hidden checkbox shows a solid block to indicate "mixed hidden-ness", and "? Selection.Range.Font.Hidden" shows 9999999 to indicate 'undefined" state.

WHY does the .Hidden property become unreliable/unreadable when the selection is in a table and the selection is relatively many rows? This does not happen when the Selection in a non-table. This is messing up a program of mine that is otherwise very good.

Comment: I don't know why it happens. How about you try looping over all the cells and setting the hidden property for each one? eg `Selection.Range.Cells(i).Range.Font.Hidden`

Comment: wow!! ..... happens when you select 50 or more cells. the paragraph format also becomes undefined  .... you could do `for each aaa in selection.paragraphs` ... `.... aaa.range.font.hidden ....`

Comment: Every table cell contains at least one paragraph. Observe that there also is a table paragraph at the end of each table row, outside the last cell. If a paragraph's font within the selection, whether inside a cell or outside a cell, is different from the text font you would really have an undefined `Hidden` property. However, I doubt that these paragraphs can really be made hidden without hiding the table or a row. Therefore the selection should always be undefined if it includes a table-paragraph mark.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts so far, but note that the failure to recognize hidden-ness is a matter of the quantity of cells or rows in the selection, not a matter of how the .Hidden property got set or whether there are paragraph marks in the cells. Did we find a Word bug?

Comment: If it's a bug it has been there fore a very long time. It isn't limited to the Hidden property, either. Try SpaceBefore, Font.Name or Font.Size. My explanation may be quite lay but it serves me well. I don't expect to be able to apply paragraph or font formats to several cells with one command. Not from the keyboard, and not using VBA.

Comment: In my testing it happens only when I select MORE than 50 cells. If I select 1Cx50R or 5x10R all good, BUT as soon as I go over 50... My cells are blank and I am NOT selecting the end-of-row character.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth this is not specific to tables; the exact same thing happens in a document that has 51 blank (but otherwise identical) paragraphs. If you select 50 paragraphs you can get real results for:

```
?selection.Range.Paragraphs.Count  ' just to confirm the selection
?selection.Font.name
?selection.Range.Font.Hidden
```

BUT as soon as you select the 51st paragraph things lose definition, so to speak.

I imagine that looping over your table row by row (as suggested by @jsotola) would be a good workaround.

To answer the question as to WHY this happens, well the best anyone outside of MS can do (I think) is speculate. If I were to speculate I would suggest that there is some sort of internal limit or limitation when it comes to processing or storing detailed information for so many paragraphs.  Is it a bug, I think so (but that is just IMHO).

---

**Function to replace the buggy built-in function**

Example of a function that will return True, False or wdUndefined (9999999) depending on whether font is Hidden, Visible or a mixture of Hidden & Visible (i.e. undefined), respectively.

Note that it is entirely possible for wdUndefined to be a valid result as an otherwise visible paragraph may have a single character hidden by font and therefore that paragraph's font would neither be entirely visible, not hidden - so it is 'undefined' - hence wdUndefined is very valid.

Example usage and output:

```
?selection.Paragraphs.Count
 2016 

?fontIsHidden '(automatically operates on the active selection)
 False
```

The function:

```
' Put this code into a STANDARD module
Function fontIsHidden() As Variant ' Variant to return True, False, wdUndefined
    Dim paraSelected As Paragraph
    Dim NotFirstPara As Boolean
    Dim result As String

    For Each paraSelected In Selection.Range.Paragraphs
        ' This could be done with Table.Rows instead of Paragraps
        ' (but would error if there was no table)
        If NotFirstPara Then
            If paraSelected.Previous.Range.Font.Hidden <> paraSelected.Range.Font.Hidden Then
                result = wdUndefined ' this para is different to the previous paras
                Exit For
            End If
        Else
            ' Setup for the first paragraph
            Select Case paraSelected.Range.Font.Hidden
                Case False ' 0
                    result = False

                Case True ' -1
                    result = True

                Case wdUndefined
                    result = "Undefined" ' some text in the para is visible and some is hidden

            End Select

            NotFirstPara = True
        End If

    Next paraSelected

    fontIsHidden = result

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks to all who puzzled over this so far. I think it's a Word bug. My workaround is as follows. I make the assumption that the hidden-ness (or other property of the selection like .Font or .Underline) of the the selection is "uniform"  ... that I can try to read the property of the first 10 characters rather than the entire selection.

Comment: @BruceM - if your assumption that hidden-ness is uniform is valid then you really only need to test a portion of your data (as little as a single table cell depending on whether you mean uniform across the table, row or column) - I shall edit my proposed answer to elaborate...

Comment: @BruceM have you had a chance to test this yet?

Comment: It also happens in tables, in nearly identical fashion. Create a table with 1 column and 51 rows. Keep it blank. Select 50 rows and `Selection.Font.Size=11`, but select 51 rows and it's `Selection.Font.Size=9999999`.

Comment: And now I've just discovered it happens right in the main document UI too. It can be seen as follows: create a new document with 51 paragraphs. Highlight the first 50 of them. The font controls for name & size are available. Highlight all 51 paragraphs, and all the font controls become grayed out & unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who puzzled over this bug in MS Word. My workaround is as follows. I make the assumption that the hidden-ness (or other property of the selection like .Font or .Underline) of the the selection is "uniform"  ... that I can try to read the property of the first 10 characters rather than the entire selection, and still get the right answer. If you do not know that your entire selection has the same properties as the first 10 characters of your selection, this solution won't help you.

```
Function DigDeeperInto(fullSelection As Selection) As String
' This returns the truth of the hidden-ness of the *front end* of a Selection.
' This is used because Word sometimes mis-reads the hidden-ness of a whole Selection.
   Dim shortRange As Range ' will hold the just the front end of the full Selection
   Dim theTruth As String
   Set shortRange = fullSelection.Range
   shortRange.SetRange Start:=shortRange.Start + 1, End:=shortRange.Start + 10
   If shortRange.Font.Hidden = wdUndefined Then theTruth = "UnDef" ' this Function failed
   If shortRange.Font.Hidden = 0 Then theTruth = "Visible"
   If shortRange.Font.Hidden = -1 Then theTruth = "Hidden"
   DigDeeperInto = theTruth
End Function
```

After selecting a Selection, and assuming that Selection.Font.Hidden will not be reported correctly, I call the DigDeeperInto(Selection) function. It looks at only the first 10 characters and returns a string "Visible", "Hidden", or "UnDef". If it still returns "UnDef" (which does not happen for me, luckily), that would indicate DigDeeperInto() failed to solve the problem.

Comment: I respectfully question whether your assumption is valid...  UnDef is a valid result, you can test by adding 3 characters to a blank doc, make the middle character .hidden then query using `?selection.range.font.hidden` - the overall result must be UnDef :)

Comment: You are right that wdUndefined indicates mixed hidden-ness of the chars in a selection, but the probable bug is that the .Hidden property (and others) returns wdUndefined if the actual state of the selection is uniform but the selection is relatively large.

Comment: I agree there is a bug, see my updated answer which provides a function that works for large selections (tested with 2016 Paras).  If it works for you please mark as an answer, cheers